# Are These Legitimate Tossed-Away Votes For President Trump Found At An Oklahoma Wedding?

Tags: us-elections-2020

A [recent](https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2020/11/two-men-found-trash-wedding-reception-closed-polling-place-stunning-video/) [News](https://gellerreport.com/2020/11/wedding-party-ffind-trump-ballots-in-trash.html/) [story](https://stateofthenation.co/?p=35906) reports a wedding party finding torn-apart ballots, the majority of which are marked for President Trump.

While the majority of the sites that I've found this story on are pro-Trump sites, I'm not seeing anything suspicious in the articles themselves, or the video that the majority of these articles have included.

Are these legitimate ballots, the majority of which have been cast for Trump, that have been thrown out?  It is already noted in the video that such ballots wouldn't change Oklahoma's results - since Oklahoma is deep red - so this question is only asking about the validity of the torn-up ballots.

Comment: Reminder: Comments are not a race to post you unreferenced, partisan opinions on which might have happened.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the Oklahoma State Election Board ([via Twitter](https://twitter.com/OKelections/status/1325909914590588929)):

> This video is from pct 469 / subpct 457 in Tulsa County. These are clearly "spoiled ballots" where the voter mistakenly marked more than one option in a race. Spoiled ballots are returned to the precinct clerk and destroyed, then the voter is issued a new ballot.

They use screenshots from the video to highlight this point. Here are some of the examples they show - they annotated the video to circle the part of the ballot that shows it is "spoiled":

[image: spoiled ballot 1]

[image: spoiled ballot 2]

They also referenced the [relevant statute](https://www.oscn.net/applications/oscn/DeliverDocument.asp?CiteID=78569):

> "Should a voter spoil any ballot in an effort to vote the same, the voter shall... return it to the clerk. The clerk shall destroy the ballot in the presence of the voter and shall issue the voter another ballot..."

And they show a redacted photo of the spoiled ballot affadavit for that polling location, with signatures of 11 voters who had spoiled ballots:

[image: spoiled ballot affadavit]

Answer (score 11):

**There is no credible evidence to support this.**

The only evidence here is [a few guys talking on a video](https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2020/11/two-men-found-trash-wedding-reception-closed-polling-place-stunning-video/). We can't verify anything they say, not even that they were actually at a wedding in Oklahoma, never mind anything they claim about ballots.

The most obvious deficiency is that anyone who seriously believes they have found evidence of voter fraud should be reporting it to the relevant authorities so it can be investigated, and a thorough examination made of the ballots and other evidence. [They have not done that](https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2020/11/two-men-found-trash-wedding-reception-closed-polling-place-stunning-video/). (If they had it would be national news, like the [report of ballots in a dumpster in Georgia.](https://www.fox5atlanta.com/news/spalding-county-sheriff-no-ballots-found-in-dumpster-outside-elections-office)) Their behaviour has been entirely consistent with that of someone wanting to get a bit of attention by making sensational allegations.

Other flaws in the story:

- The reports disagree about when the wedding took place. [The first link says voting had "taken place earlier in the day"](https://www.thegatewaypundit.com/2020/11/two-men-found-trash-wedding-reception-closed-polling-place-stunning-video/). [The second says "earlier in the week".](https://gellerreport.com/2020/11/wedding-party-ffind-trump-ballots-in-trash.html/) It is hugely unlikely that a wedding is booked into a polling station venue on election day, given polls don't close until 7pm.
- Assuming the most likely timing is correct, several days elapsed between voting and the alleged wedding, during which time we are asked to believe that nobody emptied the trash cans - especially the alleged people who allegedly dumped the alleged ballots and would allegedly be keen to remove the evidence of their crime.
- [Physical ballot boxes are not generally openable at the polling station.](http://aceproject.org/main/english/vc/index.htm) Instead they are not opened until they are taken to the counting office. Someone would have had to break open the boxes to get at the completed ballot papers, which would have been noticed (and been a major incident) at the counting office.
- [Other cases have shown that many papers look somewhat like ballots used for voting,](https://www.fox5atlanta.com/news/spalding-county-sheriff-no-ballots-found-in-dumpster-outside-elections-office) including sample ballots, unused ballots, and papers printed on a home computer made to look like ballots

Comment: Or what about spoiled ballots?  Someone is filling out their ballot and they make a mistake, so they ask for a new one.  I don't know what the normal procedure for that would be in Oklahoma, but throwing the old one in the trash, maybe after ripping it up so that it isn't mistaken for a valid ballot, wouldn't seem totally unreasonable.

Comment: And of course in a place where the majority of voters support Trump, it would stand to reason that the majority of spoiled ballots would be marked for him.  Especially since US President is usually the first race on any ballot, so most people would already have marked their vote for that race before they got to wherever they made a mistake.

Comment: "The most obvious deficiency...": On the other hand, many people who may be inclined to suspect fraud may also be people who would not trust the "relevant authorities" to investigate properly, and who would see announcing it to the general public as a more effective way to stimulate action.  I wouldn't write off the claim on this basis alone (though I would on many other bases).

Comment: I'm sure Rudy Giuliani would have taken it off their hands. But you are right, theoretically the people might have been so dumb they found evidence of massive electoral fraud threatening the country and decided to put it on social media but not keep it.. That's why I write "no credible evidence" rather than "this is false".

Comment: "They have not done that." Citation-needed

Comment: "Several days elapsed between voting and the alleged wedding" - According to the first link the wedding was held "where voting took place earlier in the day,"  so this needs a reference.

Comment: @NateEldredge Procedures will vary, but an account of working in a Pennsylvania polling station says that ballot papers were counted out when issued and then counted by the machine during voting, and the totals compared. Spoiled ballot papers are kept as part of the evidence that no ballots were dumped.  https://portal.drewdevault.com/2020/11/10/2020-Election-worker.gmi

Comment: @Oddthinking Given the upload date of the video and other sources reporting it as a week after the election day, it seems like the first article is incorrect about the day on which this occurred.

Comment: @Oddthinking From the second link "A wedding was hosted in the same building where voting had taken place the week prior." If there is conflicting information about when the wedding took place, that reduces the credibility even more. Also polls close at 7pm in Oklahoma. Is it really likely that a wedding is booked into a polling station for that evening after polls have closed and the cleanup finishes?

Comment: @Oddthinking "Citation needed". If they had reported this it would be national news, just like the alleged ballots reported in the dumpster in Georgia.

Comment: This answer is bringing a knife to a gunfight. In the red corner, The Gateway Pundit, a news site that is one of the top 1000 web sites in the world (According to Alexa, but I am rather dubious. Really?) explicitly claims X. In the Blue Corner, a couple of random Internet denizens have posted comments here saying that, in their opinion, X doesn't seem likely, given the circumstantial evidence. Why should anyone believe this? The premise of this site is that we bring in referenced evidence, not IMOs, to evaluate the claims.

Comment: If you believe the massive outpourings of evidence-free accusations from extremist right-wing sites to be "a gun" and the truth coupled with real analysis to be "a knife" then I am proud to be bringing a knife to a gunfight. "The race is not always to the swift, nor the battle to the strong".

Comment: I appreciate that Oddthinking's use of words is a bit inflammatory here, but he makes a good point - this answer provides a lot of discussion on reasons why it seems unreliable, but does not cite any source to support it - at the very least citation for similar assumptions (voter fraud actually reported to authorities, examples of valid ballots to compare).  This answer is not without merit, but the criticism is reasonable, and it's why I've elected to accept the newly-posted answer that does cite the Oklahoma State Election Board's discrediting of the story.

Comment: I just upvoted that answer myself, and I encourage others to do so too. It was only just posted, and it's a much better answer than mine.

Comment: This answer is blatantly shirking the requirement for citations. Add some or it will be deleted.